# When using a RegEx in AutoFixture ISpecimenBuilder, Why do I always get back the same value?

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing, autofixture

My builder is set up to either deal with a Parameter or a Property.  This may change in the future, but for now this is what I have in my builder:

```
public class UserNameBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
       var propertyInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.Name == "UserName" && propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            return GetUserName();
        }

        var parameterInfo = request as ParameterInfo;
        if (parameterInfo != null && parameterInfo.Name == "userName" && parameterInfo.ParameterType == typeof(string))
        {
            return GetUserName();
        }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }

    static object GetUserName()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        return new SpecimenContext(fixture).Resolve(new RegularExpressionRequest(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{6,30}$"));
    }
}
```

My UserName object is a ValueType object and is as follows:

```
public class UserName : SemanticType<string>
{
    private static readonly Regex ValidPattern = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{6,30}$");

    public UserName(string userName) : base(IsValid, userName)
    {
        Guard.NotNull(() => userName, userName);
        Guard.IsValid(() => userName, userName, IsValid, "Invalid username");
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string candidate)
    {
        return ValidPattern.IsMatch(candidate);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string candidate, out UserName userName)
    {
        userName = null;

        try
        {
            userName = new UserName(candidate);
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The UserName class inherits from SemanticType which is a project that provides a base for my value types.

Whenever I use AutoFixture as follows:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(new UserNameBuilder());

var userName = fixture.Create<UserName>();
```

I always get the value "......"  I thought I would get a different value each time.  Is what I'm seeing expected behavior?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through it ?

Comment: In my code, yes, but not in the AutoFixture source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, [favor negated character classes instead of the `dot`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and try to [use the `dot` sparingly](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[._](?![.])){6,30}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The above Regular Expression matches text that also gets matched by the original one provided in question, e.g. `nik_s.bax_vanis`.

It also makes AutoFixture generate different text as well (pardon my F#):

```ml
// PM> Install-Package Unquote
// PM> Install-Package AutoFixture
// PM> Install-Package FsCheck.Xunit

open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Ploeh.AutoFixture
open Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Property>]
let ``Generated strings from RegEx are not all the same`` (PositiveInt count) =
    let fixture = new Fixture()
    let context = new SpecimenContext(fixture)

    let results = seq {
        for i in 1 .. count do
            yield context.Resolve(
                new RegularExpressionRequest("^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[._](?![.])){6,30}$")) }

    let threshold = count / 10
    results |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.length >! threshold
```

---

The original Regular Expression is fine. – It's the *engine* that repeats the `dot` as many times as possible:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{6,30}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks you @Nikos, the new RegEx pattern was a big help.  To start out I just simply substituted the new pattern for the old pattern.  I do get results that are different than before, i.e., I no longer receive a string of 6 dots.  However, my code loops 50 time to generate 50 fake database records, and I still get a repeated result from my builder.  Is this because of my code vs. what you wrote?  I am not familiar with F# so I did not translate it.

Comment: You *may* get the same results over time when trying to generate text that matches a given Regular Expression.

Comment: One way to generate 50 unique strings that match a given Regular Expression is to use the `ISpecimenBuilder` shown in your question combined with a `Generator<string>` in your test code.

Comment: Or rather a `Generator<UserName>`.

Comment: I ended up doing this to generate my 50 unique UserName records:
`IEnumerable sut = new Generator<UserName>(fixture);`
`var actual = sut.OfType<UserName>().Distinct().Take(MaxDbEntries);`